# Forbid router from creating a subnet?

Tags: networking, router, lan, subnet

A switch (`device A`) connects two wall Ethernet sockets in different rooms. Each room contains exactly one wall socket. One room contains storage media with Ethernet connection (`device B`), which is plugged into the wall socket. Another room contains a TV-box-gizmo-thingy (`device C`), which has a single Ethernet input and a HDMI output, providing the user's HDMI TV with internet connection and LAN access, and a Wi-Fi router (`device D`). Sketch below.

[image]

My goal is to set the TV room up in order to:

1. cover it with Wi-Fi
2. provide internet access to the TV
3. provide `device B` (network disk) access to the TV

When I connect `device C` to the wall socket, leaving `device D` untouched, goals 2 and 3 are achieved, but not 1.

When I connect `device D` to the wall socket, leaving `device C` untouched, goal 1 is achieved, but not 2 and 3.

The obvious solution would be to connect the router (`device D`) to the wall socket through WAN and the TV-gizmo (`device C`) to the router through LAN, but then the TV-gizmo loses access to the disk (goal 3) for some reason. I assume it is because the router places it in a different subnet and then, although the disk is still reachable from `device C` (tested using by replacing `device C` by a laptop and `nmap`/`ping`), its primitive algorithm doesn't realize that. Is it possible to set-up the router somehow in order to not create a different subnet, so that devices `C` and `D` appear as connected to `device A` directly? If not, what sort of a networking device do I need to achieve this apparent behavior? A hub?

No clue how TV-gizmo works and (please) assume that it is impossible to find out (ancient, no documentation). Can you please provide any solution given these four devices? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Hook up Routers LAN to LAN (NOT LAN to WAN) to ensure you put everything on ONE subnet.

So:

```
(1) LAN to LAN
(2) Give second router a static IP on your network.
(3) Turn DHCP OFF on the second router.
```

This makes your second router a simple extension of your network.

Comment: So you're saying that if I perform these steps, `device D` will still be able to provide wireless connection to other devices in the same room? How do devices wirelessly connected to `device D` acquire IP addresses, can you please explain?

Comment: You may need a Wireless Router with an Ethernet port if your router does not have an Ethernet port.  Hooking up routers by Ethernet as I outlined is how to solve your problem. Inexpensive wireless does not hook up this way.

Comment: Very cool, +1, will try out tomorrow, accept if works. Thanks.

Comment: For your interest, I extended wireless to my second floor with a Ubiquiti Access Point and POE connection to the main router.